# Customize Bubble chart's tooltip from Google Charts API

Tags: php, javascript, tooltip, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I'm trying to change the tooltip of the bubbles in the Bubble Chart from Google API.

The role:tooltip, which would solve my problem, doesn't work with this kind of charts.

Right now my bubble shows information about the values of the rows, which is correct according the documentation, but I only need that information to draw the chart and I need to show a string as the tooltip. This string is composed by some of the values, which I need to format.

Can this be done?

For the record I'm using PHP to serve the data through JSON to the Javascript and I'm using the latest API from google (https://www.google.com/jsapi).

This is my columns definition as they are right now:

```
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'ID', 'label' => 'ID', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'Fecha', 'label' => 'Fecha', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'h', 'label' => 'h', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'stringRes', 'label' => 'Valor', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'Resultado', 'label' => 'Resultado', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number');
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

**[SOLUTION]**

If someone is asking the same question, I solved my problem by just erasing the labels of the fields which I didn't want to show, and that was it!

I changed my columns model to this:

```
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'ID', 'label' => 'Fecha', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'Fecha', 'label' => '', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'h', 'label' => '', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'stringRes', 'label' => 'Resultado', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'Resultado', 'label' => '', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number');
```

Thanks @jmac for giving some approach on my problem.

Comment: If you could add your solution to the answers below, and then check your own answer as "solved" it would help to show the problem as resolved and let others see the question/answer if they need it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLUTION]**

If someone is asking the same question, I solved my problem by just erasing the labels of the fields which I didn't want to show, and that was it!

I changed my columns model to this:

```
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'ID', 'label' => 'Fecha', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'Fecha', 'label' => '', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'h', 'label' => '', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'stringRes', 'label' => 'Resultado', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'Resultado', 'label' => '', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number');
```

Thanks @jmac for giving some approach on my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setFormattedValue()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setFormattedValue) on your data in order to use a value to draw the chart, and a different number to pop up when you mouseover it. Because you are importing data and we can't see the format, there isn't much we can do to tell you exactly how to handle it, but here is an example:

```
var drawVisualizations = function() {
  // Create and populate a data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Force');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Level');

  // Add 2 rows.
  // google.visualization.DataTable.addRows() can take a 2-dim array of values.
  data.addRows([['Fire', 1], ['Water', 5]]);

  // Add one more row.
  data.addRow(['sand', 4]);

  // Draw a table with this data table.
  var originalVisualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('original_data_table'));
  originalVisualization.draw(data);

  // Clone the data table and modify it a little.
  var modifiedData = data.clone();

  // Modify existing cell.
  modifiedData.setFormattedValue(1, 1, "one");

  // Draw a table with this data table.
  var modifiedVisualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('modified_data_table'));
  modifiedVisualization.draw(modifiedData);
}
```

In your case you'll need to create a function to loop through your data table and format your items as you'd like, but at any rate this will give you the ability to make a number plot as one thing, but display as another.